# Spring boot return exit code for CommandLine app

Tags: java, spring-boot, exit-code

I have a Spring Boot application implemented CommandLineRunner. I wanted to return -1 as exit code if there is any error/exception happens and return 0 if no exception.

```
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // to do stuff. exception may happen here.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        readSetting(args);
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args).close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("######## main ########");
        java.util.Date end_time = new java.util.Date();                                         
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        logger.error(SystemConfig.AppName + " System issue end at " + end_time);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
...
}
```

I have tried System.exit(), SpringApplication.exit(MyApplication.context, exitCodeGenerator), etc. But it still return 0 when I throw an exception!

I have tried solutions from here:

https://sdqali.in/blog/2016/04/17/programmable-exit-codes-for-spring-command-line-applications/

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication&method=exit

Please help!

Comment: maybe you should move `System.exit(-1)` to `public void run` and not use it in the main.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, I tried that too, still returning 0.

Comment: Your first source mentions the ExitCodeGenerator. The only thing you are missing is calling SpringApplication.exit, See my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a nice article answering your question on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-exit-codes. Here is the gist:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CLI implements CommandLineRunner, ExitCodeGenerator {

    private int exitCode; // initialized with 0

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(CLI.class, args)));
    }

    /**
     * This is overridden from CommandLineRunner
     */
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        // Do what you have to do, but don't call System.exit in your code
        this.exitCode = 1;
    }

    /**
     * This is overridden from ExitCodeGenerator
     */
    @Override
    public int getExitCode() {
        return this.exitCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple runners, is this a valid solution as wouldn't it force an exit?

Comment: @Wolsie All ExitCodeGenerator's getExitCode functions are called, then the resulting exit code is returned by SpringApplication.exit and passed to System.exit, which terminates the VM, i.e. as long as you donæt have a System.exit anywhere else, the VM is terminated after all ExitGenerators have executed their getExitCode function.